# Google Map: Set Viewing Angle On Map Programmatically

Tags: android, google-maps

I am new to Google Map API on Android.
I have a default position and when I click to start Google Map, it shows the location in a 3D view (The screenshot on Left), but i actually prefer the screenshot on the right hand side (Remark: not related to the magnification issue)

How would I set the preference programmatically in Android?

```
MapFragment mapFragment = (MapFragment)getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map_fragment);
mMap=mapFragment.getMap();

mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(mPosition, 13));
CameraUpdate zoom = CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(18);
mMap.animateCamera(zoom);

mMarker=mMap.addMarker(setMarkerOptions(markerTitle,markerMsg,mPosition));
mMarker.setDraggable(true);
}


private MarkerOptions setMarkerOptions(String title,String msg,LatLng position){
 MarkerOptions options=new MarkerOptions(); 

options.title(title);
options.snippet(msg);
options.position(position);

return options;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Post the code snippet you have for the Google Map.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you are aiming to change here is the Map's [Tilt (viewing angle)](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/views#tilt_viewing_angle). You can set the tilt at the part before calling `mMap.animateCamera`. In the Camera and View docs for Google Maps, it is included there on how to [Change the Camera Position](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/views#changing_camera_position):

> **Changing camera position**
>
> There are two convenience methods for the common position changes. CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(LatLng) gives you a CameraUpdate that changes the camera's latitude and longitude, while preserving all other properties. CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(LatLng, float) gives you a CameraUpdate that changes the camera's latitude, longitude and zoom, while preserving all other properties.
>
> For full flexibility in changing the camera position, use CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(CameraPosition) which gives you a CameraUpdate that moves the camera to the given position. A [CameraPosition](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/CameraPosition.html#public-constructors) can be obtained either directly, using new CameraPosition() or with a CameraPosition.Builder using new CameraPosition.Builder().

I specifically linked the `CameraPosition` object since it has a constructor that allows you to provide a `float tilt` value.

I'm not entirely sure if this is the only way, but do look around the docs and I'm pretty sure that you'll find what you need from there. Cheers! :D

Comment: CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
    .target(1stlocation)     
    .zoom(12)                   
    .bearing(300)                
    .tilt(30)                   
    .build();     


    map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.green))
    .position(1st Location)
    .flat(true)
    .rotation(245));


  map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition ),
    30000, null);

Comment: Thanks for your information, i used CameraPosition with .tilt(0) and i get the result i want.

Comment: No worries. Happy coding. Cheers! :D